# 405 method not found. On localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So I'm making a form that puts info into my local mysql db. But I stuck when I try to POST it. I getting "405 method not found" when try to debbug. I'm sing xampp for my virtual DB, maybe it's because of that?
The code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Kasmetinių atostogų prašymas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Kasmetinių atostogų prašymas</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
  <form id="requestForm" method="POST"  target="_blank">

    <input type="date" name="request_date" id="input_field" placeholder="Prašymo data"  required></br></br>

    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Vardas" id="input_field" required></br></br>

    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Pavardė" id="input_field" ></br></br>

    <input type="number" name="personal_code" placeholder="Asmens kodas" id="input_field" min="11" max="11" ></br></br>

    <input type="text" name="p_address" placeholder="Jūsų adresas" id="input_field" ></br></br>

    <input type="date" name="requestDateFrom" id="input_field" placeholder="Atostogos nuo"  ></br></br>

    <input type="date" name="requestDateTo" id="input_field" placeholder="Atostogos iki"  ></br></br>

    <input type="number" name="daysNumber" placeholder="Atostogų dienų skaičius" id="input_field" ></br></br>
  </br>
  <Input type="button" name="submit_button" id="buttonLast" value="Patvirtinti">
  </form>
</div>  
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonLast").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:5500/insert.php",
        type: "POST", 
        data:$("#requestForm").serialize(),
        success:function(response)
        {
          alert("Well done!");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is php code to connect db and post info into specific columns. 
For the purpose of test I trying to post just from the 3 cols.
PHP:

```
<?php



$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

if(!$con)
{
  echo 'Connection problems';
}
else
{
  echo 'Ok';
}


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$date = $_POST['requestDate'];
$name=$_POST['firstName'];
$lname = $_POST['lastName'];


$query = "insert into info (date,name,lname) values ('$date','$name','$lname')";


if($con->query($query) === true )
{
  echo 'Duomenys išsaugoti!';
}
else{
  echo 'Duomenų nepavyko išsaugoti!';
}
}
header("refresh:2; url=index.html");
?>
```

Comment: Probably CORS, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers

Comment: Correct jquery Ajax call should be `method: "POST", ` not `type: "POST", `

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed ( copied from wiki )
A request method is not supported for the requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form that requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
type: "POST"
```

to

```
method:"POST"
```

Other error you might encounter:

You are using requestDate in php but request_date in html. Similar for other params.

Update:
Add cors header to Ajax call

```
url:"http://127.0.0.1:5500/insert.php",
method: "POST", 
headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
},
data:$("#requestForm").serialize(),
success:function(response)
{
  alert("Well done!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  First part didn't helped, still getting an error. Second part fixed.

Comment: you changed xampp port listening to 5500?

Comment: Actually did it. Not working but getting one more error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404."
Seems same error.

Comment: add this in ajax call headers:{Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *} and retry get

Comment: Can you please tell me how excactly I should add it? Example please :)

Comment: So added this:<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
 But still getting error. 
Don't know how to add it in the ajax always getting syntax error.

Comment: @ArtūrasYapaz i just updated answer with code to replace ajax call. nothing to be donw on php. Leave as it was

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("submit", "#requestForm", function (event) {$.ajax({
    url:"https://127.0.0.1:5500/insert.php",
    type: "POST", 
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    success:function(response)
    {
      alert("Well done!");
    }
  });
});
```

Try this Jquery Code.

Comment: Not working. By the way input type is button so "on submit" is not the option I guess?

Comment: https://127.0.0.1:5500/insert.php

Change To 

http://localhost/insert.php